# Why is the magnetic Schrödinger operator positive?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, mathematical-physics, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics

In the book *Schrödinger Operators* by Cycon et al. they prove that the magnetic Schrödinger operator (as well as the Pauli operator) have essential spectrum $\sigma_{ess} = [0,\infty)$ if $B$ has decay at infinity and the potential $V$ is $-\Delta$-compact.

Remember that the magnetic Schrödinger operator is given by

$$H_{ms} := (-i\nabla -A)^2 +V $$

where $A$ is the vector potential. In their proof they claim that since $H(A,0)= (-i\nabla - A)^2$ is **positive**, the spectrum must be contained in $[0,\infty)$.

A self-adjoint operator $T$ is positive means that $\langle Tx,x\rangle \geq 0$ for all $x\in X$ where $X$ is Banach. Now why is $H(A,0)$ positive? Is it because it is the square of an operator, specifically $-i\nabla -A$? If so is it trivial to see this?

Comment: Hint: prove $-i\nabla-A$ is Hermitian.

Comment: @J.G. This is clear to me. I was wondering whether the square of a hermitian operator is always positive.

Comment: @J.G.  But $-i\nabla-A$ is not Hermitian because it does not map a complex-valued function to a complex-valued function.  It takes a complex-value function and returns a vector-valued function.  A Hermitian operator must map from a Hilbert space into the same space, by definition.

Comment: @Zvi That's only a minor concern; the square of this vector-valued operator is a sum of squares of "ordinary" Hermitian operators, by Pythagoras. When I call a vector Hermitian, I just mean its components are, since that causes the vector to also be self-adjoint (if its adjoint is defined in the obvious way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is a vector with Hermitian components, $$\langle\psi |X\cdot X|\psi\rangle=\sum_i\langle\psi |X_i^2| \psi\rangle=\sum_i\langle\psi |X_i^TX_i| \psi\rangle=\sum_i\Vert X_i|\psi\rangle\Vert^2\ge 0.$$

Comment: Well that solves it.

Comment: @JakobElias  This solution needs to be somehow fixed in my opinion.  Read my comment under the question.  This map $X=-i\nabla-A$ is not Hermitian.

Comment: @Zvi Sorry for replying to your comment underneath the OP instead of this question; I'm having internet problems ATM that are making it hard to keep up with the page's updates.

Comment: I see how your argument works now.  But, if you don't mind, I will add your comment in the answer.  You can remove it if you don't like it.

Comment: @Zvi Following a community rejection of your suggested edit, I've modified the algebra a little to incorporate the comment's point.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\mathcal{H}$ denote the Hilbert space of wave functions $\psi:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{C}$.  Recall that
$$\langle u|v\rangle =\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3}\bar{u}(x,y,z)\ v(x,y,z)\ dx\ dy\ dz$$
for all $u,v\in \mathcal{H}$.  Write $h$ for the operator $(-i\nabla -A)^2$.  Observe that
\begin{align}\langle hu|v\rangle &=\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3}\overline{hu}(x,y,z)\ v(x,y,z)\ dx\ dy\ dz
\\&=\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3}(i\nabla -A)^2\bar{u}(x,y,z)\ v(x,y,z)\ dx\ dy\ dz
\\&=\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3}(i\nabla -A)\cdot \overline{\Phi u}(x,y,z)\ v(x,y,z)\ dx\ dy\ dz,
\end{align}
where $\Phi=-i\nabla-A$.  That is,
\begin{align}\langle hu|v\rangle &=i\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3}\nabla\cdot \overline{\Phi u}(x,y,z)\ v(x,y,z)\ dx\ dy\ dz-\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3} \overline{\Phi u}(x,y,z)\cdot Av(x,y,z)\ dx\ dy\ dz
\\&=-i\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3}\overline{\Phi u}(x,y,z)\cdot \nabla v(x,y,z)\ dx\ dy\ dz
-\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3}\overline{\Phi u}(x,y,z)\cdot Av(x,y,z)\ dx\ dy\ dz,\end{align}
where we apply [integration by parts in higher dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Higher_dimensions), assuming that $u(x,y,z)$ and $v(x,y,z)$ vanish quickly when $(x,y,z)$ is large.  That is,
\begin{align}\langle hu|v\rangle &=\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3}\overline{\Phi u}(x,y,z)\cdot(-i\nabla-A)v(x,y,z)\ dx\ dy\ dz
\\&=\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3}\overline{\Phi u}(x,y,z)\cdot\Phi v(x,y,z)\ dx\ dy\ dz.
\end{align}
In particular,
\begin{align}\langle hu|u\rangle &=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\overline{\Phi u}(x,y,z)\cdot\Phi u(x,y,z)\ dx\ dy\ dz\\&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\big\Vert\Phi u(x,y,z)\big\Vert^2\ dx\ dy\ dz\geq 0\end{align}